# PHP Curl Post Request - not sending payload

Tags: php, curl, post

I'm trying to set up a proxy server to make a post request. Problem is when I make the request I am not seeing the payload.

One thing I notice is that curl seems to be adding an extra "boundary" to the content-type in the request.

Am I missing something?

**The Code:**

```
$contentType = $_SERVER["HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE"];
$post = http_build_query($_POST);
$ch = curl_init();     
$header = array("Content-Type:" . $contentType,
        "Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br",
        "Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8",
        "Connection:keep-alive",
        "User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36",
        "Cache-Control:max-age=0",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1",
        "Origin:<url here>");

echo "<b>POST</b><br>" . var_dump($_POST) . "<br><br>";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($_POST));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookiejar.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch); 

$headerSent = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT );
echo "<b>Request Header</b><br>$headerSent<br><br>";

$header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$header = substr($result, 0, $header_size);
$body = substr($result, $header_size);


echo "<b>Response Header</b><br>$header<br><br>";
echo "<b>Response Body</b><br>$body";
```

**Response**

```
$_POST = array(5) { ["formFields_Complaint_Type"]=> string(9) "1-GM2-226" 
["formFields_Descriptor_1"]=> string(10) "1-GM3-3085" 
["formFields_Descriptor_2"]=> string(9) "1-GM4-903" 
["formFields_Date/Time_of_Occurrence"]=> string(0) "" ["_target1"]=> string(1) " " }
```

Request Header:

```
POST <relative address> HTTP/1.1 Host: <url> 
Cookie: 
JSESSIONID=mDMJZQdLV4bhvJQ6vPyQvxqHVTynGS3byBnYsTpjDvY1xBnB93R8!-759339305!-1867032216 Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8 
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br 
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8 
Connection:keep-alive 
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36 
Cache-Control:max-age=0 Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1 
Origin: <url>
Content-Length: 633 
Expect: 100-continue 
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----
WebKitFormBoundarybdBepqnmjSF86t50; boundary=------------------------
f8e2ad22b9bb626c
```

Comment: when debugging curl, always enable `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` - do that, and try again, and post that output. that said, you're doing a couple of mistakes which i might comment on when i get time

Answer (score 2):

best guess: your (biggest, code-breaking, but not only) problem is that the target server supports only `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`-encoded POST requests, but your curl code converts both `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`-encoded requests, and `multipart/form-data` requests to `multipart/form-data`, regardless of what the client used. (this is because PHP transparently translates both of them to an equal native PHP array called $_POST)

this will use `multipart/form-data` encoding:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);
```

this will use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($_POST));
```

you must decide which encoding to use, based on `$_SERVER["HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE"];`

- and if its neither of those (for example, if its `application/json`), you must add special code to handle each, and you should probably error out whenever $_SERVER["HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE"]; is not 1 of the types you have made a special case for (like raw $_POST for multipart, and http_build_query($_POST) x-www-form-urlencoded)
- also you're not forwarding arbitrary http headers, you should probably add some code for that
- and if you really need to support `Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1` header, you need to implement specific code to handle that at the proxy side (go read the http specs on the subject - https://www.w3.org/TR/upgrade-insecure-requests/ )
- and you say to the target that you accept `Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br` , but provide no code to decode any of them, so it will look like garbage binary data to the client if the target server decide to use any of them (curl can decode them for you though, using CURLOPT_ENCODING, if libcurl was compiled with gzip and deflate and br support. i've never seen a libcurl with br support, and i bet your curl doesn't have it. probably have gzip/deflate support compiled-in though)